# Converting String into Arraylist

Tags: java, android

I have a large text file and I want to put it into ArrayList. My text file contain # signs at start, here is text file data.

```
  #These classes define the style and structure for your dialog, but you should use a DialogFragment as a container for your dialog. The DialogFragment class provides all the controls you need to create your dialog and manage its appearance, instead of calling methods on the Dialog object.
  #These classes define the style and structure for your dialog, but you should use a DialogFragment as a container for your dialog. The DialogFragment class provides all the controls you need to create your dialog and manage its appearance, instead of calling methods on the Dialog object.
  #These classes define the style and structure for your dialog, but you should use a DialogFragment as a container for your dialog. The DialogFragment class provides all the controls you need to create your dialog and manage its appearance, instead of calling methods on the Dialog object.
```

Comment: Use `String.split("#")` to convert to `String[]` and use `Arrays.asList()`

Comment: You should have a try before asking something in SO, if you try and can't get it by yourself that's when the SO users will try to help you.

Comment: What have you tried?  What methods have you considered using?  What did you learn when you searched Google and the existing questions here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to split a String in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481828/how-to-split-a-string-in-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split the String using the following code

```
String[] divide = string.split("#");
```

then you can use

```
List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(divide));
```

This will convert String array to ArrayList.